# How to attach a database by mdf file that has not been detached

Tags: sql-server, mdf

**Issue:**

OS hard disk was broke before DB backing up, the original .mdf and .ldf files can be transferred but those .mdf and .ldf files can not be attached by SQL Server Management Studio directly.

Comment: I have found the solution, post it for sharing

Comment: I think only steps 4 and 7 are needed. It's better to use `CREATE DATABASE...FOR ATTACH` for step 7.

Comment: you should post the solution as an answer and flag it as the unswer to close the thread

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks for your suggestions. but the original .mdf were not detached as normal and we can't attach it directly as normal too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

*Assuming the DB name is ‘Sample’ and DB files path is ‘D:\DB’*

Step 1: Open Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to create a New Database with 
Database name: Sample
Path:  D:\DB

Step2: Stop the DB Server

Step3: Delete Sample.mdf and Sample.ldf files from folder D:\DB

Step4: Copy the old Sample.mdf to the folder D:\DB

Step5: Start the DB Server

Step6: execute the following sql to detach DB

exec sp_detach_db Sample,'true'

Step7: execute the following sql to attach DB and then refresh

exec sp_attach_single_file_db 'Sample','D:/DB/Sample.mdf'

Comment: Thanks! I thought my issue was caused by permissions, but I think instead it was caused by not detatching my databases. These steps allowed me to reattach my databases.